# enforce "PC-view" in sharepoint link

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, mobile-view

When I send a mail to my users I sometimes want to link o a sharepoint site.

If the users clicks on this link from a mobile, I want to enforce PC-view, since Im pointing at a page with a web part, and the web part is not visible in mobile view ... any secret querystring-value that Im not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the site:

> In order to deactivate SharePoint Mobile feature in Office 365 sites
>   go to Site Settings >> Manage site features. Look for “Mobile Browser
>   View” and click Deactivate button.